# How do I meet new people in my new yoga class?

Tags: united-states, approach, groups, exercise, activities

I have recently started going regularly to yoga, where there are a number of people that I find interesting and would like to get to know better, due to the nature of yoga I find that it would be bad taste to try to talk to people during the yoga class or while the teacher is teaching. Please keep in mind I know nothing about yoga as I have just started learning.

What are some subtle ways to strike up a conversation with people that I find interesting either before or after class?

Comment: Something you find interesting on them sounds like a nice topic to start a conversation. Else, it's important the topic is connected to the yoga class. But once you start a conversation like this you can go to sports, your sedentary job, how you experience the spiritual level of yoga or what do you think of the teacher's personality. I wouldn't start a talk in the class, tho.

Comment: Please remember to comment why you are voting to close so I can try to fix it by editing the question.

Comment: Do people leave immediately after class? Sometimes people form small gathering after class, you can join them and introduced yourself then

Comment: Joe, the close vote reason is "too broad". Do you have any more information you could add to make this more specific? Perhaps what you are trying to gain from this interaction - help with yoga? - new friends? What makes them interesting to you? When I took yoga classes, there was no time to chat before or during class because everyone was quiet and either focused on the upcoming class or listening to the instructions during class. I never got to know the people because there was no social interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from the background of a martial arts class, i'd recommend **becoming more involved in the lessons**.

After a shared experience like a yoga class, it can be easy to strike up conversation about some *techniques you learned*, a *movement or pose you're having trouble with*, or *the lesson itself* (how the instructor dealt with a topic, the pace of the teaching, etc).

The people who you're sharing the class with are likely to **have a lot in common with you** about these topics, and they will have just spent an hour with you being physical, so they aren't likely to be uncomfortable talking with you.

To become more involved in the class, you could try some of these suggestions - but it will all come more easily with time.

- Be active in the classes and engage with the system
- Interact with your teacher when appropriate*
- Think actively about the lesson content, try to explain it to someone afterwards in private to deepen your understanding
- Practice in your own time

*This *appropriate*ness may vary according to the discipline - in a martial arts class, I find it only appropriate to comment on something with the instructor if we've been training together for a long time, or if there is a comedic moment in the class - your situation might be a little less relaxed, so perhaps limit your talking to the end of the lesson.